# `gx` not opening url in gvim but works in terminal

Tags: gvim

I use vim in the terminal as well as gvim. My issue is that in the terminal <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> opens urls without a problem but in gVim nothing happens.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a fix?

I'm using gvim 7.4 with patches 1-52.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant but maybe you should precise which OS you're using. Also I have the same behavior on a Debian with gVim 7.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tried this on a debian with XFCE desktop environment and I can reproduce the issue. Turns out, that gvim calls xdg-open URL to open the URL, but unfortunately, this did not return anything or display an error message.

However, I could fix this, by using `setsid xdg-open` which you need to set for the g:netrw

```
:let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="setsid xdg-open"
```

Bug opened with [XFCE](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12251)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm on Ubuntu with Gnome so I made a slight change: let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="setsid gnome-open"

Comment: Could you please explain why `setsid` fixes the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Same happens on Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04: When I use the setting with `setsid` it pulls the html doc into the gvim window.  When I use `let g:netrw_browsex_viewer= "gnome-open"` just a screen flicker no browser.  When I use `gnome-open` from bash works fine, so what's the problem with Ubuntu gnome?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on OS X and running the following command in vim worked for me:

```
let g:netrw_browser_viewer='open'
```